# Ember build blocked by corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, ember.js, proxy, ember-cli

I am forced to use an older version of ember-cli (0.1.2) and node (0.10.33) and npm (1.4.28) and work behind a corporate proxy.

I have set my proxy within `npm` and running `npm install` completes successfully.

However, when I run ember build, my `vendor.js` contains `HTML` pages returned by my corporate proxy, which say I haven't provided my credentials. As a result when I try to `ember s` the browser can't parse the `vendor.js` file and blows up.

Does anyone know how to tell `ember-cli` to use my working `npm` proxy settings? I've tried approximately 12,034 different formats of strings in `npm` all of which work, but none of which allow `ember-cli` to build properly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *my vendor.js contains HTML pages returned by my corporate proxy*?

Comment: I mean that after the end of one package in the concatanted `vendor.js` the next package starts with `<html><h1>An error from my proxy server about not being authenticated</h1></html>`

Comment: Is the file maybe like this already in your bower_components, node_modules or something you `app.import`? `ember-cli` itself does *not* make a network request during `ember build` or `ember serve`.

Answer (score 0):

To help others this was a strange combination of issues:

1. The application `bower.json` had a reference to some packages with `http://a-cdn/package/package.js`
2. When running `bower install` it was able to resolve those urls and downloaded the files into `bower_components`
3. There were reference to the downloaded `package.js` files in the brocfile
4. When running `ember build` it tried to request the files from the `http` endpoints and wasn't able to because of our corporate proxy.
5. As a workaround, I changed the `http://cdn` links to the current version of the packages in question

In short, this I suspect was misconfiguration by the previous developers. I don't see why I would need a reference to the `http://cdn` version of bower packages, as this wouldn't ensure a specific version and avoid the bower cache during `ember build`.

Comment: Especially bower dependencies *must* be `app.import`'ed. They are *not* included automatically. You can *only* import from `bower_components` and your `vendor` folder. So this part seems pretty normal to me.

Comment: Sorry yeah I had a bit of a mental block during that comment. What was strange is that the reference to the package in the `bower.json` pointing to  and `http` based url which then makes an `http` request each time during `ember build` instead of checking the cache. 

I guess it's a separate issue the fact that `bower install` works on the command line but not via `ember build`